# How do I use hibernate to query for a list of some entity based on its many-to-many property without filtering out items on the many-to-many property?

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, criteria

I have an entity class `Foo` that has a many-to-many relationship with `Bar`

```
...
<class name="Foo">
    ...
    <set name="bars" table="FooBar" lazy="true" batch-size="100" fetch="select">
        <key column="FooID" />
        <many-to-many column="BarID" class="Bar" />
    </set>
    ...
</class>
...
```

I am trying to make a search screen that allows users to search for all `Foo`s that are attached to a specific `Bar`.  All `Bar`s attached to each `Foo` should be shown in the search result.

So I tried this code:

```
criteria.createAlias("bars", "bar", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("bar.id", barID));
```

This filters the `Foo` records just fine.  But it also filters the `bars` property.  So I added this line:

```
criteria.setFetchMode("bars", FetchMode.SELECT)
```

But that didn't do anything.

I don't have any hibernate filters on Bar on the hibernate session.  Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

when you have filters on collection items the collection is not initialised and later lazyly fetched on access. Maybe Hibernate can not match bar and barId. Try

```
criteria.createAlias("bars", "bar", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("bar.id", barID));
```

Answer (score 0):

Tom, since you want to return `Foo`s attached to a specific `Bar`, you do not need to use a left join.  You can use an inner join and then the `Bar`s will be fetched via N+1 selects (1 select to get the filtered `Foo`s, and then one select per `Foo` returned to get its `Bar`s).

I have very similar code to yours above, and I noticed that the left join would force the `Bar`s collection to be loaded from the initial result set, while an inner join would use N+1 selects.  I also tried specifying the fetch mode to no effect.  In my case, I can't use an inner join because I use filters that require a left join.  For example:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.not(Restrictions.ilike("bar.name", "FizzBuzz")));
```

In that case, a `Foo` without `Bar`'s should be returned because it has no `Bar` whose name is "FizzBuzz", but using an inner join would eliminate all `Foo` without `Bar`s.  If anyone else could provide an alternative answer to Tom's question that still uses a left join, it would be much appreciated!

Edit: I found a Hibernate bug report which states that "criteria.setFetchMode gets ignored if you combine it with createCriteria to add a restriction":

https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-3524